# Embed Static Carto Map in Google Sheet Cell

Tags: carto, html, google-docs, google-drive

Carto is mapping software that provides me with a url to a dynamic map.

I want to show a static version of the map (which updates daily) in a google sheets cell.

Ideally there would be a way to manipulate the carto url to show as an image and just use the IMAGE function in google sheets.

It doesn't seem possible, so I may have to use google app scripts, I've never used before and have no experience with html, so would be good to get some specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

CARTO has [Static Maps API](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/static-maps-api/) which gives you image URL for your map, and you should be able to use it in IMAGE function, or just Insert>Image feature